# Como faço para o Django enxergar as pastas do meu computador?

Tags: python, django, vue.js

Preciso fazer com que meu sistema enxergue pastas que estejam fora da sua pasta, para renderizar os .pdfs que estão dentro dessas pastas. Estou utilizando uma função no javascript (Vue.js) muito simples, semelhante a esta:

```
get_doc(doc_name) {
  return '/static/pdf_docs/' + doc_name;
}
```

Só que, além de ser deselegante, me obriga a deixar todos os arquivos .pdf na pasta static. Tentei alguns procedimentos mais não consegui. Agradeço a ajuda desde já.

Comment: vc configurou o [media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/howto/static-files/)?, geralmente se usa um [servidor dedicado](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-dedicated-server) para servir esses tipos de arquivos

Comment: @DaviWesley, como sou iniciante em django, não sabia que era necessário fazer essa configuração. Poderia fornecer um exemplo de como posso fazer?

Comment: desculpe pela demora, então, eu nunca fiz isso em django mas acredito que seja muito fácil, tem um [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html) que mostra um exemple simples de como fazer isso.

Answer (score -1):

Geralmente [não é aconselhado](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-dedicated-server) a usar o Django pra servir arquivos em produção, usa-se um servidor dedicado como [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/).

> A maioria dos grandes sites Django usa um servidor Web separado – isto é, um que não está servindo também o Django – para servir arquivos estáticos. Este servidor roda um tipo diferente de servidor web – mais rápido mas sem tantas funcionalidades

porém, caso queira fazer isso em Django ele oferece essa funcionalidade, no [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example/24066179#24066179) tem um exemplo de como fazer isso passo a passo :)